# Vertically align images cross browser - Firefox bug

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, vertical-alignment

This is tricky to explain, see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cfd63feo/1/). Works in Chrome, not in Firefox.

I need to display a number of images within a fixed sized container and vertically align them to the middle. I have followed the examples given in this question ([How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)) which works great. But using this in my markup it is not working in Firefox.

Depending on the context of the image the html markup can be slightly different:

For example:

**Working:**

```
<div class="print-wrap">
    <ul>
        <li class="img">
            <span class="img-valign-helper"></span>
            <img class="ls img-valign" src="http://placehold.it/200x105">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Not working:**

```
    <div class="print-wrap has-size">
        <ul>
            <li class="img">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell-50 img-wrap">
                        <span class="img-valign-helper"></span>
                        <img class="ls img-valign" src="http://placehold.it/200x105">
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell-50 info-wrap">content</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Looking at this in Firebug I can see the `<span class="img-valign-helper"></span>` is slightly greyed out - I am not sure what this means?

[image]

The result is the image is vertically aligned to the top. So the `img-valign-helper` is not working. Yet works fine in Chrome. I do not see anything in my html markup which would cause this to break. The `css` is almost identical too.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `height: 100%;`  to your `.table-cell-50`. That way it can pass through the height to your helper span.

[Updated fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/0rghdgLn/)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Looking in the inspector I could see its height was the full height of the container so didn't think I needed to define it explicitly. Any ideas why this worked in Chrome then?

Comment: I only know Chrome and FF don't implement percentage heights exactly alike. Especially when you need to pass on the height through a div.